# using HLSL effect file

Tags: hlsl

I am a student and working on my final project.
The project is about image processing. 
I found a code which removes the background from an object, which is exactly what i need 
but the code is an effect file(*fx) in HLSL.
I have never worked with it and have no idea how to use it
I looked for a training for beginners and found nothing.
Is there anyone who can help me with it?
what environment do I need and how can run the effect file?
can it be added to the c# project?

thanks

Comment: HLSL is High Level Shader Language - it's like coding for the GPU. I think if you're writing code in XNA, HLSL files might be something you can include in the build process, like image content files. You could likely find a better answer asking on the Game Development section of Stack Exchange (and include as much detail as you can about your project type!)

Answer (score 0):

What are you developing for?  I see you're using C#, does that mean you're building for windows phone? or?...

This except from [Creating a Lens App - Nokia][1] might help you as this is what I've done for importing in shaders that I've created into my app.  Also, how are you accessing this shader on the UI front?  Can you paste in some code?

> Adding SharpDX References Instead of using the default DirectX
>   interoperatiblity though a separate C++ DLL, we are going to use the
>   SharpDX library to make drawing calls from C# code. This library is a
>   wrapper of the underlying DirectX functions that allow them to be used
>   in any .NET language and currently supports Windows Desktop, Windows
>   Metro and Windows Phone 8. Start by heading to the downloads section
>   and get the package of your choice: "binary only" includes the
>   libraries and "full package" has some sample code on how to perform
>   common tasks with SharpDX.
>
> Create a new directory inside your project's folder called Lib. Open
>   it and create two child folders called x86 and ARM. Decompress the
>   package you downloaded and from the Bin folder, copy the contents of
>   Standard-wp8-x86 to your x86 folder and Standard-wp8-ARM to ARM. In
>   your project, right click on References and select Add References...,
>   and in the new window click Browse and navigate to the Lib\x86 folder
>   to select the following assemblies:
>
> SharpDX.dll SharpDX.DXGI.dll SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll
>   SharpDX.Toolkit.dll SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.dll
>   ShaprDX.Toolkit.Graphics.dll Since the assemblies aren't AnyCPU, and
>   currently we only have the x86 ones referenced, we must edit our
>   project manually so the compiler references the correct ones. Close
>   Visual Studio and open your CSPROJ file in your favourite text editor
>   and look for the items named Reference, like this one:
>
> Lib\x86\SharpDX.dll
>    You need to change the x86 part of the path to
>   $(Platform), so it ends like this:
>
> Lib\$(Platform)\SharpDX.dll  What we
>   have written is a MSBuild property that gets replaced with the current
>   platform name when building the project, so the correct version of the
>   assemblies is used. Repeat this step for all existing references to
>   SharpDX. When finished, save the changes and reopen the solution in
>   Visual Studio.
>
> Note.png Note: If Visual Studio can't find the SharpDX references, go
>   to the Build > Configuration Manager... menu and change Active
>   solution platform to x86. Remember to change it again to ARM when
>   deploying to a Windows Phone 8 device.
>
> Compiling the Shader SharpDX.Toolkit fully supports FX effect files,
>   although you can only compile them at runtime in Desktop platforms. To
>   compile them to a binary format we are going to use the tkfxc.exe
>   tool, which you can find inside of the Bin\Win8Desktop-net40 folder of
>   the SharpDX binaries you downloaded. Our application will then be able
>   to load this binary blob and use it for drawing. To compile it, make
>   sure the file is in the same directory as your tkfxc.exe binary (or
>   you have it correctly added to the PATH) and execute the following
>   command in a Command Prompt window: tkfxc.exe /FoInverted.tkfxo
>   Inverted.fx This will compile the shader in a binary form and output
>   to the file Inverted.tkfxo (by default it's output.tkfxo). If
>   something bad happened you will get a red text output, so check what
>   went wrong and fix the shader until it compiles. You can output the
>   binary code to a C# source code file containing an array of byte
>   objects. To do this, specify the parameter /FcInverted.cs instead of
>   /FoInverted.tkfxo.
>
> [1]:
>   http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_a_Lens_application_that_uses_HLSL_effects_for_filters

Comment: Do you know whether or not C#/WP8 will allow for multiple different registers to be set when running the effect?  For example, having a shader with a sliding scale (intensity).